# SAPUI5: What exactly is "items" in list aggregation?

Tags: list, sapui5, aggregation, items

While binding a list with a model and template, what is "items"? And what other options are available?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51095315/

Answer (score 0):

The "items" aggregation is on of the **Aggregations** of for example a sap.m.List. You can see it mentioned [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html).
Every aggregation can be bound