# Why can I give items as property?

Tags: sapui5

The [Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table/function%20Object()%20%7B%20%5Bnative%20code%5D%20%7D) is extended from the [ListBase](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListBase). On the Table, I can you use items aggregation from ListBase as a property like as following:

```
<Table inset="false" items="{ path: '/ProductCollection', sorter: { path: 'Name' } }">
```

Why can I use `items` as a property, although is defined as aggregation?

Comment: Not sure what exactly the question is.. Are you asking what `items="{...}"` does? Or how the framework handles `items` in the background, thus "why" it works? This question is missing some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UI5, there are basically two ways of filling an aggregation. One is by adding the elements directly, and the other is to bind them to a model.

Your example shows the latter case, where the `items` aggregation is bound to the collection `/ProductCollection` in your model.

An aggregation binding consists of two parts in XML views, one is the actual binding with the "property" as you did, and the other is to specify the "template" which is used for each element in the collection.

This is also explained further in the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070):

> ```
> <mvc:View
>   controllerName="sap.ui.sample.App"
>   xmlns="sap.m"
>   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
>   <List id="companyList" items="{/companies}">
>     <items>
>       <StandardListItem
>         title="{name}"
>         description="{city}"
>       />
>     </items>
>   </List>
> </mvc:View>
> ```
>
> The List element has both an `items` attribute and a nested `items` element:
>
> - The attribute `items="{/companies}"` binds the children of our json model's `companies` array to the list. This by itself is not enough to display the `companies`, instead it sets the parent path for the binding of all contained list items and their descendants. In addition you need to declare a nested element.
> - The nested `items` element in our case contains a `StandardListItem`. This serves as a template for creating the individual list rows.

Answer (score 1):

Writing "items=..." in the XML is the same as writing "bindItems(..." or "bindAggregation('items',..." in JS. The framework knows that it is an aggregation and that you are binding the path '/ProductCollection' from your unnamend odata model to it.

As Ronnie mentioned, in the binding there are properties like 'path' or 'sorters'. You can check it here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject/methods/bindAggregation
The object oBindingInfo is the one.